# How to display a field from reference model

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, reference, mongoose-schema

I want to get the `name` of the user, using the **Reserves** model, because that's the one I can display. The **User ** model is referenced in the **Reserve ** model. and the only thing I can get is the Object ID.

How can I get other field values from the User model through the reference?

Here is the code for the user model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add a name']
    },
    idnum: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add an id number'],
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add a password']
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please select a role'],
        enum: ["Faculty", "Student Officer", "Admin"]
    },
    org: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add an organization'],
    },
    dept: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add a deparment'],
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

Here is the code for the Reserve model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const reserveSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'Users'
    },
    purpose: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add a purpose']
    },
    dept: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please choose a department']
    },
    org: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please choose an organization']
    },
    bldg: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please choose a building']
    },
    room: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add a room']
    },
    date: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add a date']
    },
    time_in: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add a starting time']
    },
    time_out: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add an ending time']
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
    },

}, {
    timestamps: true,
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Reserve', reserveSchema)
```

Then, here is the code in fetching the from the database, using the model

```
function ReservesContent({reserves}) {
  
    return (
        <div class='info-container'>
            <p id='requestor'>{reserves.user}</p>
            <p id='purpose'>{reserves.purpose}</p>
            <p id='building'>{reserves.bldg}</p>
            <p id='room'>{reserves.room}</p>
            <p id='time_in'>{reserves.time_in}</p>
            <p id='time_out'>{reserves.time_out}</p>
        </div>
    );
}


export default ReservesContent
```

```
{reserves.length > 0 ? (
                  <div>
                  {reserves.map((reserve) => (
                    <ReservesContent key={reserve._id} reserves={reserve} />
                  ))}
                  </div>
                ) : (<h3>No Reservations Found</h3>)}
```

Answer (score 0):

For that to work you need to `populate` the user reference

Here's some psudo code that demonstrates how to populate a field:

```js
Reserve.find({ /* Insert serach criteria or nothing at all */ }).populate('user');
```

I hope this helps!
Docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: thanks that could work too. but i did it by using virtuals https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and I found a way using Schema Virtuals

I added the requestor on my *reserve.model* file

```
  const reserveSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    requestor: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
  });
```

then I added a **Schema.virtual**

```
  reserveSchema.virtual('requestor-name', {
    ref: 'User',
    localField: 'requestor',
    foreignField: 'name'
  });
```

i also added that requestor field in my *reserve.controller* : `requestor:req.user.name`